# Java + JSON and "errorjava.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!" error

Tags: java, json, stub

I created an java console application, but I don't know why it returns me an error "Stub!".
This is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("{0:0}");
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

It returns me:

```
errorjava.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

How to change JSON object "{0:0}" to object (array) in java?

Comment: Your base JSON is illegal, properties should be surrounded by double quotes: `{ "0": 0 }`

Comment: but how to escape quotation marks?
`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("{ \"0\": 0 }");
jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);`
returns: errorjava.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

Comment: What do you expect your array to be? `[ 0 ]`, I gather?

Comment: Yup.
I'm just trying to receive string with JSON object (e.g.: {"foo":"bar"} ) and 'decode' it to object in java

Comment: Have you considered using Jackson? It is done for this kind of job

Comment: Many thanks for the usefull tips :). I imported the library and defined user class. But code: `User user = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":{ \"first\" : \"Joe\", \"last\" : \"Sixpack\" }}", User.class); System.out.println(user);` returns me: User@1394894

How to get firstname and lastname?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson library resolved my problem (thanks @fge).
This is working example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

class User {
    public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE };
    public static class Name {
      private String _first, _last;
      public String getFirst() { return _first; }
      public String getLast() { return _last; }
      public void setFirst(String s) { _first = s; }
      public void setLast(String s) { _last = s; }
    }
    private Gender _gender;
    private Name _name;
    private boolean _isVerified;
    private byte[] _userImage;
    public Name getName() { return _name; }
    public boolean isVerified() { return _isVerified; }
    public Gender getGender() { return _gender; }
    public byte[] getUserImage() { return _userImage; }
    public void setName(Name n) { _name = n; }
    public void setVerified(boolean b) { _isVerified = b; }
    public void setGender(Gender g) { _gender = g; }
    public void setUserImage(byte[] b) { _userImage = b; }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
        try {
            User user = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":{ \"first\" : \"Joe\", \"last\" : \"Sixpack\" }}", User.class);
            System.out.println(user.getName().getFirst());
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

it returns "Joe"